# How to accept space separated integers and store them in a vector in C++?

Tags: c++

I tried to accept *N* spaced integers, store them in a vector and print them. This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  string rawInput;
  vector<string> numbers;
  while( getline( cin, rawInput, ' ' ) )
  {
    numbers.push_back(rawInput);
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]); ++j) {
    cout << numbers[j] << " ";
  }
}
```

It doesn't work. I get no output after running this code.
Please give an example with floating point numbers and integers. Please tell me how to print them as well. Thank you.

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does incorrectly?

Comment: `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0])` makes no sense. `numbers` is a vector, not an array. Use its member functions to check how many elements it holds.

Comment: adding on to what @Mat said, use `numbers.size()` instead

Comment: @ScottHunter there was no output.

Comment: *I tried to accept N spaced integers, store them in a vector and print them* -- Usage of `std::istringstream` makes this very easy.

Comment: "there was no output" was not the FIRST thing that the program did wrong; at some point, where it *should* have printed something you were expecting, it did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For space separated integers, don't use `getline`.  The newline counts as space when constructing integers.

Try something like this:

```
std::vector<int> database;
int number;
while (cin >> number)
{
    database.push_back(number);
}
```

You may want ask yourself if there really is a need to read a line of integers (or if any kind of record is delineated by a newline).

**Edit 1: Reading space separated integers by text line**
If you **must** read by line, one method is to use `std::istringstream`:

```
std::vector<int> database;
std::string text_line;
while (getline(cin, text_line))
{
    int number;
    std::istringstream line_stream(text_line);
    while (line_stream >> number)
    {
        database.push_back(number);
    }
}
```

IMHO, reading by line adds an unnecessary level of complexity.